# problem in converting these react with material-ui class component into fuctional component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, react-functional-component

I have a problem that converting react class component into react functional component, im almost finish that converting but i'm struggling at change java script functions
here is the code working class component code change these to functional component code

[this is the class component code](https://codesandbox.io/s/6x9w9m6n7r)

Comment: checkout your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-boiler-plate-forked-3czmc?file=/src/FunctionalComponent.js). I have made a new `FunctionalComponent.js` which mimic your class component. It's not working before maybe because of version of dependencies you use.

Comment: Thank u very much bro this is what i need,

Comment: no prob. Glad to be able to help.